# Updating data in globe.gl

Tags: three.js, webgl-globe

I'm using Points Layer provided in the globe gl [library](https://github.com/vasturiano/globe.gl). But I cannot seem to update the data after setting `Globe().pointsData`.

In the following example, I created a `Globe` instance and after that, wrote a test script that invokes after 2 seconds. But after 2 seconds have elapsed, nothing is updated on the globe even though the data points have been updated.

```
const N = 1;
var gData = [...Array(N).keys()].map(() => ({
  lat: 5,
  lng: 10,
  size: 0.5,
  color: 'red'
}));

var world = Globe()
  .globeImageUrl('//unpkg.com/three-globe/example/img/earth-night.jpg')
  .pointsData(gData)
  .pointAltitude('size')
  .pointColor('color')
(document.getElementById('globeViz'))

function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved')
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  
  // Updating the data here
  gData[0].size = 1
  gData[0].lat = 30

  // Setting the updated points
  world.pointsData = gData

  console.log(world.pointsData)
}

asyncCall();
```

I'm not sure if I should call something that will trigger an update that reflects on the Globe itself. It's not apparent from the [apis](https://github.com/vasturiano/globe.gl).

Codepen implementation is [here](https://codepen.io/ssh001/pen/YzeGYpy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looking at their Points Layer API](https://github.com/vasturiano/globe.gl#points-layer), it looks like instead of `pointsData = gData`, you need to use `pointsData(gData)`

```js
async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();

  gData[0].size = 1
  gData[0].lat = 30
  gData[0].color = 'green'
  
  world.pointsData(gData)
}
```